# Creating note phone emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I want to run my program on note and samsung j7 phones but i don't know how to create a note and j7 emulator for testing my application. I read below site but this site wrote in eclipse but my application is in Android Studio and in hardware profile, default skin part, i can't browse a new skin. Please if you know, help me.

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

Answer (score 0):

you can apply skin to `emulator`. step by step  for it.

download skin file from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/emulator/emulatorOverview.do).

1. open tools--> android-->Android Virtual Device(`AVD`).
2. create new virtual Device.
3. select new Hardware Profile.
4. Default skin field choose folder that you  download
5. click finish.
6. now hardware profile will show click next .
7. select Android api level And click next.
8. click finish.
9. Start Avd